# SAP TMS & Transport Groups

Tags: sap

I am trying to access back end data of the delivery and consolidation routes that can be displayed via TMS trx. I can have the data by using the tables TCERELE and TCEDELI.

However, the link between environments are not displayed on the table when there is a "transport group" between environments like QA and PROD.

Example TMS: DEV > Transport Group (TG) > QA > TG > PROD

TCERELE and TCEDELI outputs: DEV > TG QA > TG link from TG to QA and PROD are not displayed.

Can you please help?

[image: TMS Screenshot]

[image: TCEDELI output]

Comment: Give better screenshot of what contained in your landscape, obfuscating system names and replacing with symbolic ones, your current screenshot is unreadable. And also give expected output of `TCERELI`/`TCEDELI` tables, what *should have been* there like you think, and/or give tables output for landscape w/o TG. It is not clear what are asking about

Comment: @Suncatcher added new screenshot.
In TCEDELI, I can only see one line from A41 to Delivery but i cannot see the route from Delivery to P41.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this issue does related more to domains than to transport groups.

More than likely you have your transport groups in another domains which are connected to your `A41` domain (the domain where `A41` resides) [via cross-domain link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_tm93/helpdata/en/14/c795388d62e450e10000009b38f889/content.htm?no_cache=true).

SAP have never released any documentation regarding `TCERELE`/`TCEDELI` tables so it is only a guess, but I suppose cross-domain communications are never saved in these tables.

You can reach cross-domain and cross-TG transport routes like this:

1. Go to `TCERELE` table and find your system in `INTSYS` field (marked blue on the picture). Do not forget to select the last version in version field and select proper transport layer

[image]

1. Go to `TCETARG` table and do the same but put your transport group as target in field `TARG_GROUP`

[image]

in a such way you will get all the systems that your transport group is connected to and all the clients.

Here is the landscape view from the above tables where there are a route between two systems **D and **A and transport layer which were selected on step 1

[image]

You can simplify selection in such way

```
SELECT *
  INTO TABLE @DATA(routes)
  FROM tcerele AS le
  JOIN tcetarg AS arg 
    ON le~targ_group = arg~targ_group
 WHERE le~translayer = 'XXX' 
   AND le~intsys = '**D'
   AND arg~tarsystem = '**A'
   AND le~version = ( SELECT max( version) FROM TCERELE WHERE le~translayer = 'XXX' AND le~intsys = '**D' ).
```